# How to build angular2 app for production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, gulp, systemjs

I've complete the `angular2 tour of heroes`. And I wonder what if I'd like to build this project for production. I want to add only 2 files to `index.html`: `appScripts.js` and `vendorScripts.js`. 
I've compiled my `ts` files with option `outFile` so I have my `appScripts.js` but it doesn't work. Here is some code in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function() {

    var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
        outFile: 'app.js'
    });

    var tsResult = gulp.src(['app/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

I think it's because, we have loaded some angular models like `@angular/core` in project `ts` files, and because of some systemjs stuff..

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Researching on this too, not much online. Please share if you'll find something. The tour of heroes tutorial app downloads hundreds of files 2.2 Mb in total. There's got to be a way to reduce that for prod deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the solution. You should compile your `ts` files to `js` files and then bundle them via `systemjs-builder`.
Here's my gulp task:

```
var Builder  = require("systemjs-builder");
gulp.task("builder", function() {

        var builder = new Builder(); 

        builder.loadConfig('./systemjs.config.js')
            .then(function() {
                builder.buildStatic('dist/main.js', 'public/appScript.js')
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('Build complete');
                    })
                    .catch(error);
            });
});
```

`buildStatic` method creates the final javascript file for your application.

Comment: Could you please share the the size of your production bundle?!

Comment: It's quite big. 1 415 Kb.