# Angular2 compilation for production

Tags: angular, compilation, dev-to-production

How to compile the Angualar2 and deploy for production? 
I have checked lot of websites like [This](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/) (but this gives error and  `bundle.min.js` are not usable from `index.html` -maybe I am wrong). Also tried to angular-cli but again for RC-4 this is not working.

Wondering what is the best practices, because tsc already creates the js, should they just be imported as individual file (it will be ugly to do so).

PS:
There is already questions related to this topic like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254002/how-to-build-angular2-app-for-production) . But this is the fundamental requirement , which I am unable to get answer for .

Comment: See if this helps - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#production-configuration

Comment: have you seen [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/angular-2-how-to-bundle-for-production-currently-rc3/37874643#37874643) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614743/how-to-prepare-release-version-with-systemjs-and-gulp?rq=1) ?

Comment: Here is my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280582/angular2-too-many-file-requests-on-load/38168012#38168012) based on mgechev's repository.

Answer (score 0):

I got my final answer , trust me I tried eveything stated above. May be dint worked for me except  https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack . Worked liked charm . Recommended for others. See my issue chain https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/issues/120 . [SOLVED]

Comment: Hi. Did you use angular2-webpack for an existing project you had or did you start from scratch? If it's the first option, would you mind sharing what you did to add a bit to the post? (and help me out a metric ton!)

Answer (score 0):

**First Step:**

At first run the command  in ng-cli

```
ng build
```

or

```
ng build -prod (then it will compact all files for production version)
```

**Second Step:**

Change at index.html in dist directory

```
<base href="/"> to <base href="./">
```

**Third Step:**

Put all files into server(may be htdocs in localhost or any server)

Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular-cli

ng serve --prod --aot for testing the production version on the local machine.

ng build --prod --aot to generate build for prod deployment with AOT.